# In a finite-dimensional Hilbert space convergence in norm implies convergence in coefficients under any basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am reading an article and in the proof of a theorem it states the following:

> In a finite-dimensional Hilbert space convergence in norm implies convergence in coefficients under any basis.

In this particular case, they are considering the span of a finite set of linearly independent $L^2$ functions which form a finite Hilbert space.

Can anyone provide a reference where this is proven?

Comment: See Lemma 3.1 and Theorem 3.2 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/equivnorms.pdf.  For topological vector spaces, see Theorem 2.7 of  https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/topology/finite-dim-TVS.pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where I would find a reference, but this is a corollary of the equivalence of all norms on a finite dimensional space; in particular, the result also holds in the other direction.

Indeed, given any basis $e_i$, if $v= \sum_i \alpha_i e_i$ then $N(v) := \sup_i |\alpha_i|$ i.e. $N(v) = \sup_i |v\cdot e_i|$ is easily checked to be a norm. Thus $N(v_n-v)\to 0$ iff $\|v_n-v\|\to 0$ for any other norm $\|\cdot\|$.